# After installing can't run the functions of matplotlib library

Tags: python, matplotlib, nltk

Recently after I installed matplotlib, I can't run its library functions. It is showing error message as if matplotlib is not installed.

I already have Python 3.7 installed in my windows 10 computer and it is working fine both for the interpreter and for the IDLE. After I install matplotlib, the status was ok:

```
"Successfully installed cycler-0.10.0 kiwisolver-1.1.0 matplotlib-3.1.1 numpy-1.16.4 pyparsing-2.4.0 python-dateutil-2.8.0"
```

But when I tried to run any function from the matplotlib library it was showing an error:

**Code:**

```
from nltk.corpus import udhr

languages = ['Chickasaw', 'English', 'German_Deutsch', 'Greenlandic_Inuktikut', 'Hungarian_Magyar', 'Ibibio_Efik']
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((lang, len(word)) for lang in languages for word in udhr.words(lang + '-Latin1'))
cfd.plot()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 1907, in plot
    from matplotlib import plt
ImportError: cannot import name 'plt' from 'matplotlib' (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    cfd.plot()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 1910, in plot
    'The plot function requires matplotlib to be installed.'
ValueError: The plot function requires matplotlib to be installed.See http://matplotlib.org/`
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the module `nltk`. You should consider writing a bug report to the developers.

Comment: Where is the place I can do a bug report to them? Can you please share the link?

Comment: [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nltk-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nltk-users)

Answer (score 0):

this line showing error

```
from matplotlib import plt
```

change it into

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#or
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Did that change. Now this error is coming: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    cfd.plot()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 1919, in plot
    kwargs, 'samples', sorted(set(v for c in conditions
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 1920, in <genexpr>
    if v in self
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'v' referenced before assignment

Answer (score -1):

the plt keyword you use is an abbreviation for matplotlib.pyplot so first you should import it completely and assign an object to it named plt like :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and then for plotting your data named cfd you should do the following :

```
plt.plot(cfd_xdata,cfd_ydata)
```